# When does the first recruit come back?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

During the tutorial about Assassin Recruits, after completing a mission with him about a former assassin killing off Assassin's I sent him on a mission as part of the tutorial.

The mission name is The Little Prince, the description says something about the Sultan's third son who's been held hostage by Templars, the amount of cash I would get it pathetic compared to the amount of XP which is I think 13,500, and there's no time limit, when selecting my recruit for the mission just him gave the mission a 100% chance of success.

Since it lists no time limit till he gets back I am wondering when does he come back?

Answer (score 3):

The Little Prince's assassin should return at the end of Sequence 3, after completing the mission [The Sentinel Part II.](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-revelations/Memory_10_-_The_Sentinel,_Part_II)

This is so that:

> He can advance to level 14 while on the mission. When he returns he will be leveled up to level 15, making him a [Master Assassin](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-revelations/Master_Assassin_Missions). Now he can be placed in the Galata district so it cannot be taken by Templars.

Answer (score 0):

Either toward the end of chapter 3 or the beginning of 4. You need to progress in the main storyline to get to it.